# Grails: spring security plugin - ERROR springsecurity.GormPersistentTokenRepository

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security, persistence, grails-orm

Use Grails 2.0, spring security core plugin 1.2.6.
When login, following error is printed on the console:

```
| Error 2012-02-09 12:05:35,627 ["http-bio-8090"-exec-2] ERROR springsecurity.GormPersistentTokenRepository  - Persistent token class not found: 'PersistentLogin'
```

How to fix it? I don't know exactly when it appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have the following in your `Config.groovy`, but you don't have a class called `PersistentLogin` under `grails-app/domain`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistentToken.domainClassName = 'PersistentLogin'
```

The solution is to do one of the following:

- If you don't want persistent logins, simply remove those two lines.
- If you want persistent logins, and already have the correct class, update the second line with the [fully-qualified name](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html) of the PersistentLogin class.  It may have a different name, or it may be under a different package.
- If you want persistent logins, but don't think you already have this class, re-run `grails s2-create-peristent-token <classname>`.  [See the documentation on this command here.](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ref/Scripts/s2-create-persistent-token.html)

If that last one doesn't work, you may have to manually update `Config.groovy` to point to the correct class.  I'm not 100% sure on that, because I've never run the command twice.